# There are 2 tuples for same ID in an table and the values of some other columns for those two rows are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the below query :

```
select distinct e.case_id,e.case_name,s.script_name,s.script_type,e.Result 
from executions_table e 
left outer  join scripts_table s  on s.Case_ID=e.case_id 
where e.case_id like '11%'
```

The result obtained is :

[image]

How can I choose the row which has the script_type as automation over manual for **case_id = 111** and for **case_id = 113** as there are 2 instances and  the result is passed and also choose the rows 112 where the script_type is manual and passes where there is only manual.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: So you wants only 3 row to return from your query right? also please mention the version of your database.

Comment: @mkRabbani yes I want only 3 rows . Am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 16.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter unwanted records with a `not exists` condition:

```
select distinct e.case_id, e.case_name, s.script_name, s.script_type, e.Result 
from executions_table e 
left outer  join scripts_table s on s.case_id = e.case_id 
where 
    e.case_id like '11%'
    and (
        s.script_type = 'Automation' 
        or not exists (
            select 1 
            from scripts_table s1 
            where 
                s1.case_id = s.case_id 
                and s1.script_name <> s.script_name 
                and s1.script_type = 'Automation'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the picture you took is not visible. But I will try to help as best as I can. The query you typed says `where e.case_id like '11% '`. This is not healthy. Because there may be many IDs starting with 11. I can't give a clear answer because there is no photograph of the error. But if you just want to call a query for 111 and 113, you can try `IN ()`. If it's still unsolved, you can ask for help again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct that you wants only 3 row to return from your query and If you are using MySQL version 8, you can use CTE and Row_Number to achieve your requirement-

```
WITH CTE AS(
   select distinct e.case_id,e.case_name,s.script_name,s.script_type,e.Result 
   from executions_table e 
   left outer  join scripts_table s  on s.Case_ID=e.case_id 
   where e.case_id like '11%'
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY script_type) RN 
    FROM CTE
 )

 SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE RN = 1
```